# What is needed to transform a JPanel and JButton to work with IOS, avoiding “headless” error?

Tags: java, ios, swing, jpanel, headless

I’m working through a text book example of a simple `JPanel` with `JButton`, which works fine when I run it on a Mac. When I try to run it on IOS (IpadPro) an error results, which is defined as when an environment containing a keyboard, display or mouse is expected but not found. In this case the IPadPro has a keyboard and a display. It uses touch instead of a mouse. So, my question is, what should I change in order to make this most basic program work in a touch environment, rather than with a mouse? Is there a fix?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PushCounterPanel extends JPanel {
private int count;
private JButton push;
private JLabel label;

public PushCounterPanel() {
    count=0;
    push=new JButton("Push me");
    push.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    label=new JLabel("Pushes: "+count);
    add(push);
    add(label);
    setBackground(Color.cyan);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
    
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        count++;
        label.setText("Pushes: "+count);
    }
}
}
```

As this runs on a desktop (MacBook) I thought it would run on IpadPro, but it generates this error:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:202)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:534)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
    at PushCounter.main(PushCounter.java:5)
```

Comment: How are you building and running a Java app for iOS?

Comment: I use Pico Compiler on the IOS device, and Eclipse on the Mac. Both compiled normally when coding simpler console output projects. Only when starting to use graphics does this issue emerge.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OpenJDK for iOS does not support AWT. You must try something else, like [RoboVM](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm) or [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Comment: Please correct me if I’m wrong, but it seems JavaFX is not available on IOS. Gluon would fill this niche, at $49 per month. One considers abandoning the use of Java on IOS...

Comment: Try RoboVM, it's GPL2.